# Pentaho doesn't open

Tags: java, pentaho

I'm trying to open my pentaho but it doesn't open, on the debug mode it show some errors, but I don't know what they meant and how to fix it

The errors:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_361\bin\java.exe"   "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win32;/bin" "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_361\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_361\lib\endorsed;C:\Users\valem\Downloads\pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428 (2)\data-integration\system\karaf\lib\endorsed"  "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\launcher.jar -lib ..\libswt\win32  /level:Debug 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue till I upgraded JDK to version 20 and set it up as an environment variable.

```
PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
```